# Foundation 5 off-canvas transformation

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Is there a way to transform the off-canvas navigation in Foundation 5 to a sidebar navigation?
For example the official Foundation 5 docs use visibility classes, but doesn't this kinda defeat the purpose, because of having two separate navigations?

I want to achieve something like this with Foundation 5:

[image]

Comment: This is something I will have to solve for my current clients' project as well in short order. After a cursory glance into the off-canvas styling and JS, it does not seem to be possible a the moment. The only workaround I could image would be using Interchange, but that would probably be worse than having two navigations and using visibility classes. I'll ask Zurb about their opinion, but I have the feeling that I will end up writing a drop-in replacement for off-canvas within the next two to three weeks.

Comment: This is a brilliant question. Zurb's approach does beat the whole purpose. I will see if I can put some code out there that can repurpose the off canvas navigation

Comment: I'm not exactly sure the approach you're after, but I wrote about an off canvas approach for one of my sites - http://responsivedesign.is/articles/secondary-navigation-in-responsive-design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by overriding the off-canvas CSS rules.
Here is a beginning of a solution:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .left-off-canvas-menu,
    .right-off-canvas-menu {
        position: static;
        transform: none;
        float: left;
    }
    .move-right > .inner-wrap {
        transform: none;
    }
    .main-section {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

You can play with this code on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/fQ9Js/).

Cheers,
Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually much simpler:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    div.off-canvas-wrap {
      > .inner-wrap {
        @include translate3d($off-canvas-width,0,0);
      }
    }
    div.exit-off-canvas { display: none; }
}
```